# Breakpoints in VisualStudio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

How do breakpoints in visual studio work? I'm asking this because I have some inline functions declared in the class header, and whenever I set a breakpoint in one of them, I think the IDE also puts breakpoints to wherever the function is called. Which of course makes sense, but how exactly is it done internally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you are placing breakpoint in, are inline, and that's why debugger is smartly misplacing them somewhere else. It may be you are debugging a non-Debug build. Try

- Disabling all optimizations
- Make function non-inline

Your question doesn't demand this, but you can read here [how breakpoints are implemented.](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/writing_debugger_2.aspx)

Comment: The link actually explains what I was looking for. Would disabling the optimizations make my functions non-inline, even if they are defined in the header?

Comment: For debug builds - Yes. The functions will not be compiled as inline, and it would aid in debugging.

Comment: What if you plan to access it from another module and not export it?

Comment: You mean the other DLL is "exporting" it, right? 
Well, in that case the PDB (debugging symbols), and the DLL will have information for "debugging".